# I think this review audit answer should be removed

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I don't think that this is a good review audit answer.  It's too flippant and short with no references.

It does not matter that it was accepted earlier.  As a stand alone test, I don't think it is very good and should be removed.

[I accidentally inserted RAM while PC was booting up! Worst case scenario?](https://superuser.com/review/first-answers/1149621)

Comment: Declined.......

Comment: Review questions and answers are chosen by automated systems and we cannot remove or choose specific questions to add. They are based on the queue and behaviour they are trying to encourage.

Comment: What is the reason you choose "share feedback"? What specifically is wrong with that answer? How does the answer fail to answer the question that was asked? "Share Feedback" should be selected when something about the contribution needs to be improved. If you find the answer unhelpful, downvote it, you are encouraged to downvote unhelpful answers.

Comment: @Ramhound - I was going to say that it needed supporting information.

Comment: @Mokubai - Thats strange because when I pointed such review audits out in Meta Stackoverflow,  one of the moderators removed 3 audits from the pool.  I guess the test for an audit is not how I feel about it, but "what percentage of reviewers fail it"  and "If it was a brand new question and answer, would it get treated differently".  In the case mentioned, most reviewers were failing those audits.

Comment: @RohitGupta - If you ever have any doubts about a question being an audit you can always open the question in another tab